# Access wordpress site locally on a mac from another computer windows 10 / zorrin os

Tags: wordpress

I am a beginner currently developing a website at work in wordpress locally on a mac (MAMP server). I need to install it to another laptop (with a double boot with zorrin or windows) so that my colleague can access the site and make changes. Any suggestion how to proceed from here?

I do not have a web hosting service yet.

Any help will be kindly appreciated.

Cheers 
Marc

Answer (score 1):

One (slightly complicated) solution is to choose "DHCP with manual address" in you Macs network settings (if that's possible) and use that IP address (for example `192.126.24.1`) instead of `localhost` as your server address in Wordpress.

Then anyone in the same local network can access the websites which are set up via MAMP on that computer using the IP address as your server address.

However, in Wordpress this reqires that you either use that IP address in your site's home address from the very beginning (i.e. during the WP setup procedure) or that you change *all* instances of "localhost" in your WP database to the IP address (using either a migration plugin or exporting the database, serach/replacing the address in an editor and then reimport again)

Comment: Thanks a lot Johannes ! I'll give it a go. Cheers